# Could not initialize emulated framebufferHAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I keep getting the following error when I am running hello world application on Android Studio 1.1.0?

Failed to create Context 0x3005
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    emulator: device fd:596
    Could not initialize emulated framebufferHAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, just change the graphic driver.

Comment: Good Pointer. Thank you!